# Forcing users to use SSL on main domain and sub domain. WHMCS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, whmcs

I have two major links that have SSL certificates,
www.example.com 
billing.example.com
And I want to force users to use SSL on both of them,
https://www.example.com
https://billing.example.com

I'm using WHMCS and when I put it in the settings to use billing.example.com it it acts like it's on www.example.com

I tried a few different things with .htaccess but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use .htaccess this can also be done using virtualhosts in apache's httpd.conf.
(the following assumes you run http on port 80 and https on 443)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ... some config
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm using cPanel/WHM so any changes I make to apache config files will be deleted if I make a change with cPanel/WHM.

Comment: i'm not very familiar with cPanel/WHM, but it looks like you can make it persistent using an include.  documentation here: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/InsideVHost#Using Include Files

Answer (score 1):

Named virtual hosting does not work for HTTPS because the server cannot interpret the Host header until the connection has been made, and making the connection requires the completion of the SSL encryption handshake used by HTTPS; SSL certificates (without extensions) can only have a single server host name as their subject, and thus the certificate and connection will only work for a single host name. As a result, the named virtual hosting mechanism never has a chance to operate on the incoming connection and the only remaining way to host multiple sites is to add multiple IP addresses to the host and use IP-based virtual servers.

The keys to supporting multiple sites using HTTPS and name-based virtual hosting are to use either wildcard names (specified in RFC2818) or the x509 version 3 certificate (specified in RFC3280) subject alternative names extension.

As an alternative you can bind your sites (www. and billing. to the different IP addresses on the same host).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following directive to your Apache Virtual Host Configuration.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This will always redirect to the HTTPS host.